# How to go to a page with single post from the news list

Tags: python, html, django

Can you help me with my project.
I 'm trying to go from the page with all the news to a single post, but whatever i stay in page with all news.
But if I write the address o in the address bar, everything works.

Models.py

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000, verbose_name='Название')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='articles/', verbose_name='Фото')
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Дата публикации')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='news', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор', null=True)
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='news', verbose_name='Тэг')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата обнавления')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='опубликован', verbose_name='Статус')

class Meta:
    ordering = ('title',)
    verbose_name = 'Новости'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Новости'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', kwargs={'post_slug': self.slug})
```

Views.py

```
def list_news(request):
    news = News.objects.all()
    return render(request,
                  'diplom/news/post.html',
                   {'news': news})


def single_news(request, post_slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(News, slug=post_slug)
    return render(request,
                  'diplom/news/blog-single.html',
                  {'post': post})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('news/', views.list_news, name='News'),
   path('post/<slug:post_slug>/', views.single_news, name='post')
]
```

templates

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 grid-item">
{% for news in news %}
   <div class="blog-item large-item set-bg">{{ news.image }}
       <a href="{{post.get_absolute_url}}" methods="post" >
             <div class="categories">{{ news.title }}</div>
                <h5>{{ news.text| linebreaks|truncatechars:200 }}</h5>
       </a>
            <div>
                {{ news.publish }}
                {{ news.tag }}
            </div>
    </div>
 {%endfor%}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the {% url 'url-name' param1 %} for my templates. Does this work when you use it in your template?
[URL Reversing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls)

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 grid-item">
{% for post in news %}
   <div class="blog-item large-item set-bg">{{ post.image }}
       <a href="{% url 'post' post.slug %}">
             <div class="categories">{{ post.title }}</div>
                <h5>{{ post.text|linebreaks|truncatechars:200 }}</h5>
       </a>
            <div>
                {{ post.publish }}
                {{ post.tag }}
            </div>
    </div>
 {%endfor%}
</div>
```

Also see the name of your single object is the same as your list of objects.

```html
{% for news in news %}
```

You could rename to post, then change the rest of the variables (not the link) and it should work.

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 grid-item">
{% for post in news %}
   <div class="blog-item large-item set-bg">{{ post.image }}
       <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
             <div class="categories">{{ post.title }}</div>
                <h5>{{ post.text|linebreaks|truncatechars:200 }}</h5>
       </a>
            <div>
                {{ post.publish }}
                {{ post.tag }}
            </div>
    </div>
 {%endfor%}
</div>
</div>
```

I also updated

```html
<a href="{% url 'post' news.slug %}" methods="post" >
```

to

```html
<a href="{% url 'post' news.slug %}">
```

as you are just retrieving the object and not sending information to update it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your options, unfortunately didn't works.

Comment: What is the Django debug page showing?

Comment: Django debag doesn't show anything. The news page loads again when you click on the post. If you enter the address of the post in the address bar, then everything works

Comment: if you inspect the link you are clicking using the DevTools in your browser, what does the link show?
I suspect it is redirecting you to the same list page. Confirm that the URL is correct to what you are expecting. If it isn't then your template needs to be updated to use the correct url. `<a href="{% url 'post' post.slug %}">` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. The error was in this line.

```
<a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
```

It was necessary to do this

```
<a href="{{news.get_absolute_url }}">
```